# Is there any example of compiling a java library into something wrappable with C#?

Tags: c#, java, c, wrapper

So I want to wrap a simple java library so to be able to use its functions from C#. Is it possible, how to do such thing?

BTW can we do such thing from C?

Comment: http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview/id/730502.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find Pavel Šavara's [jni4net](http://jni4net.sourceforge.net/) project very useful for this. It allows you to host the JVM and the CLR in a single process and share objects between them.

Answer (score 7):

Have you taken a look at http://www.ikvm.net/?? It seems pretty popular and according to the site:

> It is an implementation of Java for
>   Mono and the Microsoft .NET Framework.
>   It includes the following components:
>
> A Java Virtual Machine implemented in
>   .NET A .NET implementation of the Java
>   class libraries Tools that enable Java
>   and .NET interoperability

Comment: I've used IKVM in the past and it's pretty amazing! Just recompile the .jar into a .dll and you're good to go! Unfortunately, it does require that you also reference the Java runtime library DLL which is a whopping 26MB, but you gotta take the good with the bad :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways you can do this.
1) Use web services (Requires a separate process).
2) [Use JNI](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/) or some other native library.
3) Use some middleware (Queueing system)

Of course either of these would allow 2-way communications